# Unable to generate PDF using OpenHtmlToPdf

Tags: azure, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf, openhtmltopdf

I am unable to generate PDF in Azure temp folder (D://home) using OpenHtmlToPdf when referencing external images in Free App Service Plan (Shared Infrastructure). 
However I am able to generate PDF if I am using a B1 or greater Appservice plan.

I believe OpenHtmlToPdf is downloading images locally when referencing external images to generate PDF, which is failing in Shared Infrastructure or due to access rights. Let me know how to fix this if I am using Free Appservice plan.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox
Fonts are not supported in shared infrastructure and also other API calls are blocked where PDF generation won't work correctly in shared infrastructure due to some security reason mentioned in the link.